# Firebase Rules validation for multiple related records

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a denormalised data structure, shown below (simplified). This allows me to easily show the folders a user has access to and also show a list of users with access to any given folder.

```
{
  folders:{
    folder1:{
      access:{
        user1: true,
        user2: true
      }
    }
  },
  users:{
    user1:{
      folders:{
        folder1: true
      }
    },
    user2:{
      folders:{
        folder1: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to write the following as a Firebase rule?

> If a folder is deleted, it must also be deleted from the folder list of any user who has access to it.

Answer (score 0):

this will allow read and write to a folder if it in the user's folders list

```
{
    "rules" : {
        "folders" : {
            "$key" : {
                ".read" : "auth !== null && root.child('users/' + auth.uid + '/folders/' + $key).val() === true" ,
                ".write" : "auth !== null && root.child('users/' + auth.uid + '/folders/' + $key).val() === true && root.child('folders/' + $key + '/access/' + auth.uid ).val() === true"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think you will not need **access** node in `folders/$folderKey`

Comment: The access node in `folders/$folderKey` allows me to list all users who have access to the folder without looping through every user to check.

Comment: I'm looking to write a rule which will enforce "If a folder is deleted, it must also be deleted from the folder list of any user who has access to it".

Comment: checkout the edit , this will prevent write if folder is not exists event if it listed in user's folders list

Comment: if you want to delete a folder from the folders list of user you should use `multi path update`

Comment: I'm using `multi path update`. I want to ensure this update will _not_ succeed because it would leave user2 with bad data. `{"/folders/folder1": null, "/users/user1/folders/folder1": null}`